# Finding binomial coefficients of product of two binomials

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Suppose the expression is given like this:
$(1+x) ^{10} (1+x)^{20}$. How can I find out the coefficient of $x^m$ in the above expression, given that $0≤m≤20$.

Comment: First of all, simplify to $(1+x)^{30}$. Then, use $$(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k$$

Answer (score 1):

Using binomial expansion, the problem can be solved. For example, if *m* = 7, you know that 7 can be written as 7+0, 6+1, 5+2, 4+3, 3+4, 2+5, 1+6 or 0+7.

Now, using the result above, break down the expression into two separate expressions, and find the coefficient for each of the required powers of *x* using the formula for *n*th term of a binomial expansion.