# Sum of the series in terms of coefficient of $x^m$ in some binomial expansion.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation

It is written in my book that:
<sup>10</sup>C<sub>0</sub>×<sup>20</sup>C<sub>m</sub> + <sup>10</sup>C<sub>1</sub>×<sup>20</sup>C<sub>m-1</sub>+ ... +
<sup>10</sup>C<sub>m</sub>×<sup>20</sup>C<sub>0</sub> = coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{10}(1+x)^{20}$. I'm in doubt how this happened.

Comment: Closely related to : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872880/finding-binomial-coefficients-of-product-of-two-binomials#comment3837987_1872880

Comment: The given sum is equal to $\binom{30}{m}$, the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(x+1)^{30}$. Maybe, it can be proven via induction, that the sum above is $\binom {30}{m}$

Comment: The terms in the sum give the number of ways to chose $a$ objects out of $10$ and $b$ objects out of $20$ , where $a+b=m$. The number of possibilities to choose $m$ out of $30$ is $\binom{30}{m}$. Look at "hypergeometric distribution" to see what it means and how it can be calculated.

Comment: The products of the binomial coefficients come from the coefficients of  $(x+1)^{10}$ and $(x+1)^{20}$. If we sum up the products , for which the sum of the exponents is $m$ , we get the coefficient of $x^m$. In practice, one would simplify to $(x+1)^{30}$ instead of calculating the sum, which would be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a particular case of [Vandemonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity). By the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$(1+x)^N(1+x)^M=\left(\sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k}x^k\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^M \binom{M}{j}x^j\right)$$
So the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of the above product is
$$\sum_{k+j=m} \binom{N}{k}\binom{M}{j}=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{N}{k}\binom{M}{m-k}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The binomial theorem gives us the following:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$$

So that $$(1+x)^{10} (1+x)^{20}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}x^k \right)\left(\sum_{r=0}^{20}\binom{20}{r}x^r\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\sum_{r=0}^{20}\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{r}x^{k+r}$$

Let $u=k+r$ then $$\sum_{k=0}^{10}\sum_{u=k}^{20+k}\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{u-k}x^{u}=\sum_{u=0}^{30}\sum_{k=0}^{u}\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{u-k}x^{u}$$

EDIT: Apparently, this result can be taken directly from Vandermonde's identity, but what I did is simply interchange the sums...